# Loop when i config 301 redirect in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I config my .htaccess like this:

```
Redirect 301 /ranking https://mysite.com.br/ranking/sobre
```

But in url return

https://mysite.com.br/ranking/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/sobre/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RedirectMatch` instead that supports regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(ranking)/?$ https://mysite.com.br/$1/sobre
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Also make sure this is your top rule.